# How to remove the insert a line break chars from my string?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to display a multiline text from an API, the problem I'm facing is that the insert new line chars are displayed how do I format it to create a new line instead of displaying the chars[image]

```
<pancake:PancakeView Margin="20,40,20,40" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" BorderColor="#0071bc"  BorderThickness="3"  BorderDrawingStyle="Outside"  CornerRadius="60,0,0,60" IsClippedToBounds="true" BorderIsDashed="true" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" HeightRequest="150">
  <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">
      <StackLayout>
            <Label x:Name="lblTitle" Margin="0,32,0,0" Text="MULTI-COLOR GRADIENT BACKGROUNDS" FontFamily="{StaticResource LatoBold}" HorizontalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
            <Label x:Name="lblContent" Text="Create good-looking multi-colored gradients too!" FontFamily="{StaticResource LatoRegular}" FontSize="14" Margin="0,8,0,16" HorizontalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>

        </StackLayout>
 </ScrollView>
</pancake:PancakeView>
```

Comment: You are receiving an HTML content and should decode it first. Can you try (if available in xamarin) `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode` before setting the text? Or can you try setting (if available) the innerHTML or equivalent property of the control?

Comment: When I decode using HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(NoticeDetail); it now shows the html tags like <br/> <strong/> <li></li> etc

Comment: Ok, do you have a SetHTML kind of property in lblContent?

Comment: I think the API you are using is returning content to be rendered in a web browser. Does the API have any parameters to return the content formatted for rendering in different formats such as rich text etc?

Comment: No, the API does not take any parameters for text formatting

Comment: On to the fun stuff! If you want to show HTML in your Label you can now use the new TextType property. You can set this to Text or HTML, depending on what you want to show. You can also toggle between these two to show the source and formatted text. FROM: https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin/html-in-your-xamarin-forms-label/

Comment: Thanks setting the Texttype to html worked

Comment: Ok. Can you please mark as answer if I put it down as an answer below?

Answer (score 0):

The API you are calling is returning HTML content, and luckily the TextType property of the Label class allows you to render HTML content in your Label.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#display-html

This is from the documentation: Label instances can display HTML by setting the Label.TextType property to Html, and the Label.Text property to a HTML string

```
Label label = new Label
{
    Text = "This is <strong style=\"color:red\">HTML</strong> text.",
    TextType = TextType.Html
};
```